# unable to click on popup ok button in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I don`t why this  protractor code work for popups.
My protractor version : 4.0.3  chrome version: chromedriver_2.22.exe

below is the Error message that i am getting

Failed: no alert open
      (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
  Stack:
    NoSuchAlertError: no alert open
      (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

HTML Script for the popup

```
<div class="modal-content" modal-transclude=""><div class="popupAlert popupAlert-full marginNone ng-scope">
    <div class="popup-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title ng-binding" id="myModalLabel">You are leaving this page </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-body">
        <div class="row Margin0">
            <p class="text ng-binding">By continuing all the SLI data will be lost.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-footer">
        <div class="row Margin0">
            <a data-ng-click="cancel()" class="pull-right buttonLink2">Cancel
            <button type="button" class="pull-right swc_button" focus-element="autofocus" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="ok()">Ok</button>
        </a></div><a data-ng-click="cancel()" class="pull-right buttonLink2">
    </a></div><a data-ng-click="cancel()" class="pull-right buttonLink2">
</a></div></div>
```

## Protractor code

var popupAlert = browser.switchTo().alert();

```
    var alertText = popupAlert.getText();
    console.log(" Alert text :" +alertText);
   popupAlert.accept();
```

//expect(popupAlert.accept).toBeDefined();

Answer (score 1):

`browser.switchTo().alert()` will work only if your pop up is a Javascript alert box. In your scenario,the pop up is generated using  HTML code and it can be captured as a normal webelement. use below code to accept the pop up.

```
element(by.css(".popupAlert")).isDisplayed().then(function(isDisplayed){    
  if(isDisplayed){
      element(by.css(".popup-footer a")).click() //to close the alert
      //or
     element(by.css(".popup-footer button")).click() //to accept the alert
   }
})
```

Comment: Even if it is HTML popup but still we need to Switch then only i will able to click on the cancel link or click on submit button

Comment: HTML popup is nothing but a div element that is overlapped over your webpage. Those popups are called as Modal windows. have a look at sample bootstrap modal windows for better understanding on how modal windows works. [Bootstrap modal windows] (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Sudarshan's answer you don't have a javascript alert there, it is a simple html popup.

however since the popup takes sometime to be displayed, in my experience with use of ExpectedConditions it could be captured efficiently.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var popup = $('popupAlert');
var okButton = element(by.buttonText('Ok')); //pls use appropriate locators incase this doesn't work!
popup.click();
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(okButton),5000);
okButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have written code to open up the alert box.

Do this is by using **browser.pause().** This acts like a breakpoint in protractor, use it after doing a action to open the alert box and use key **c** to continue the protractor test step by step( dont wait too long else protractor will throw a timeout exception).

Comment: Yes i have written

Comment: browser.get("url);

Comment: element(by.linkText(linktext_locator)).click();

Comment: browser.sleep(5000);

after this only i have alert code handling

Comment: is it a default alert box or a custom made popup for your project? If it is a custom made then switchTo().alert() wont work. You have to access it only via class name